# Test Regex with new line string \n via PHPUnit

Tags: phpunit, newline

I created a php library that parse content via regex. One of this regex is `'#\n-{3,}#'` to parse `---` only with an break, a new line, before.

I have also tests written in PHPUnit for all methods and always I get a failure for tests with the new line regex. I test always with [`assertSame()`](https://phpunit.de/manual/6.5/en/appendixes.assertions.html#appendixes.assertions.assertSame)

I tried to set as input the follow strings:

1. `$input = PHP_EOL . '---';`
2. `$input = '<br>---';`
3. `$input = '
   ---'; // with break in code`

As expected I set:

- `'<hr/>'`

However always it fail and get an error. If I send this variables to the assert check it will fail and parse not the new line. Only without the `\n` inside the Regex, like `'#-{3,}#'`, it works fine without error for the tests.

Also if I use as input for the test a new line with a string before, it works also, like

- `$input = "test\n---";`

But I would like also to test without string, only start with a new line.

The parse for front end works fine, it replace via this regex from my markdown file if the content is include a break and followed by the 3 `-`.

How is it possible to set as input for the `assertSame()` function in PHPUnit a new line before the string?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are using single quotes in your pattern.

In PHP `\n` means "new line" in a string only if double quotes are used.

```
$input = PHP_EOL . '---';

preg_match("#\n-{3,}#", $input); // this will match
```

See https://3v4l.org/EpEGf